# Uninstall H2O in Windows 10

Tags: uninstallation, h2o

As my plan was to exclusively use H2O's web GUI, I installed H2O following these steps: https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/downloading.html#download-and-run-from-the-command-line. I got a Windows Firewall popup asking me to allow h2o to communicate on public networks (I was connected to a public network at that moment). I accepted.

Now I would like to uninstall it, but I have not been able to find info about it. Also, it does not appear in the list of installed applications in Windows 10 settings. I have not found any rules related to H2O or port 54321 in Windows firewall either.

Please note:

- This is the first time I install programs this way.
- I do not have Python or R installed in my computer, as it was not necessary for using H2O's web GUI.

Comment: do you want to uninstall H2O-3 because of the Firewall popup or is it completely unrelated? If so, we can maybe help you configuring your Firewall, but you can be sure that H2O doesn't make requests on its own to the public network.

Comment: Otherwise, if you simply want to remove H2O-3 from your computer, you just need to ensure that the Java process is terminated, and then delete the `h2o-3.x.x` folder obtained when unzipping the downloaded archive: there's nothing else H2O-related installed on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling a simply a matter of deleting the H2O jar file in your case.

To my knowledge Windows will only open the port for the given piece of software. Once you remove H2O from your computer the firewall rule will no longer apply.

This is more of a Windows-firewall question rather than H2O question, so please take my answer with a grain of salt.